# When to use Service Layer Validation and Entity Class (Data Annotation) Validation?

Tags: validation

Can you provide an example to better understand this..

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this as often as you can.  Setting your data annotations is going to enforce the validations at the server side, ensuring that as your data comes in it meets the validations, regardless of what other validation was completed.